# Select from end of table until selection contains a number of valid values

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite table like the following:

```
gary_ages
====================
Name     | Age
--------------------
Gary 1   | 20
Gary 2   | 50
Gary 3   | 35
Gary 4   | 71
Gary 5   | 50
Gary 6   | 4
Gary 7   | 50
Gary 8   | 65
Gary 9   | 91
Gary 10  | 50
Gary 11  | 0
```

You can see that Garies 2, 5, 7 and 10 are 50 years old.

I would like to make a selection, starting from the end of the table, that contains 3 Garies whose age is 50. In this case that selection would range inclusively from Gary 5 to Gary 11.

- The selection contains 3 Garies aged 50.
- It would *not* include Gary 2, as then it would contain 4 Garies aged 50, and I only want 3.
- The selection *does* include Gary 11, because Gary 11 is at the end of the table which is where the selection starts.
- The selection *does* include all Garies between 5 and 11, even though not all of them are aged 50.
- The selection *does not* include Garies 3 and 4, because the selection already has 3 Garies aged 50 and doesn't care about any more Garies.

Using SQLite via Python, I can do this fairly easily by selecting the final row of the table, checking if the total count of 50's is 3, and either selecting the next row or returning the current selection as a Python list depending. But ideally I'd like to confine this to the SQLite world.

Is there a simple solution?

```sql
SELECT * FROM gary_ages WHERE ...
```

Comment: What determines order so you know what "last" is?

Comment: @Shawn Good point. In this case let's assume rowid.

Comment: All other conditions remaining the same, what if there are less than 3 rows that match Age == 50?  For example if there are only two rows overall that match Age ==50:  In that case, should the results 1) be empty (i.e. return zero rows), or 2) return all rows including and following the 2nd match, or 3) return all rows?  The Python logic you describe at the end would return all rows in this case, but strictly according to your bullet points the select should fail if there are not 3 matching rows.  My other comments indicate that both answers behavior differently in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that

```
SELECT * FROM gary_ages WHERE rowid >= (SELECT min(rowid) FROM (SELECT rowid FROM gary_ages WHERE Age = 50 ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 3));
```

Will return :-

[image]

That is

- the innermost sub-query is selecting the 3 latest 50 years olds,
- the outer sub-query is then selecting the lowest rowid from the 3 latest 50 year olds,
- the lowest rowid being used to drive the WHERE clause which will include all rowid's that are equal to or larger than the derived lowest rowid.

Comment: Compared to the other solution using window functions (i.e. OVER clause), this is a *great example of how basic SQL is not only sufficient, but apparently more efficient*.  With appropriate indexes defined, this query can choose only the innermost 3 records with minimal processing.  The query with the windowing function must process every row of the innermost query just to determine number 3.  (I'm guessing that no query optimizer... especially sqlite's optimizer and again when defined as an CTE... will use the outer condition to limit processing of the inner query.)

Comment: However, consider the case when there are less than 3 rows with Age == 50.  For example, if there are only two rows that match the condition, this query will still return rows *with no obvious indication that there are less than 3 required rows*.  Are the 3 rows are a necessary condition (i.e. absolute requirement)?  Shawn's query will return zero (0) rows due a null result if the matching 3 rows are not found.  Strictly the first bulleted condition in the question requires there to be 3 matching rows, but only the OP will know what behavior is desired in the insufficient case.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
WITH ranked AS
 (SELECT rowid, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY rowid DESC) AS rn
  FROM gary_ages
  WHERE age = 50)
SELECT name
FROM gary_ages
WHERE rowid >= (SELECT rowid FROM ranked WHERE rn = 3)
ORDER BY rowid;
```

```
name
----------
Gary 5
Gary 6
Gary 7
Gary 8
Gary 9
Gary 10
Gary 11
```

(Note: Requires Sqlite 3.25 or newer for `row_number()`)